# Disabling gRPC load balancing on server side output

Tags: load-balancing, grpc, grpc-java

I'm facing issue with my gRPC communication. The concern is that I need to keep the order of my events. The events are sent over multiple streams but coming from only one thread. I need to keep that order on client side for my states to be consistent.

For testing I send a message on stream1 and stream2 alternately (message on 1, then message on 2, then message on 1, etc.).

I was able to disable the threading part of client by modifying the executors:

```
.withExecutor(new SerialExecutor(new DirectExecutor()));

class DirectExecutor implements Executor
{
  public void execute(Runnable r)
  {
     r.run();
  }
}

private class SerialExecutor implements Executor
{
  final Queue<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayDeque<>();
  final Executor executor;
  Runnable active;

  SerialExecutor(Executor executor)
  {
     this.executor = executor;
  }

  public synchronized void execute(Runnable r)
  {
     tasks.add(() -> {
        try
        {
           r.run();
        } finally
        {
           scheduleNext();
        }
     });
     if (active == null)
     {
        scheduleNext();
     }
  }

  protected synchronized void scheduleNext()
  {
     if ((active = tasks.poll()) != null)
     {
        executor.execute(active);
     }
  }
}
```

Now after loading a little bit my system and checking again I still have the issue. I get randomly 5 messages on stream1, then 2 on stream2, then 1 on stream1, then 3 on stream2, etc.

My question is: how can I control the server to avoid that kind of output load balancing?

On client side I fixed it by using executor but I feel like it is only used for reception.

Answer (score 0):

inter stream order is not guaranteed in http2 layer. your best bet is client generates a sequence number, so you can handle it in order on the server side. or using a single stream (probably not an option).

btw, load balancing has special meaning. your problem is not related to load balancing.